# How to get the all nodes of the top level root node in n-ary tree?

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, binary-tree, tree-traversal

I have tree structure represented as below. It has nodes part of group and group can have subgroup. The structure is represented in XML as follows. If if pass any Node in this structure then we need to return the top level node in this structure. For example, simply if we pass Node3 id 1004 then the algorithm should return Node1,Node2,Node3. If we pass Node5 id 1008 then the algorithm should return GroupB's all nodes <Node4,Node5,Node6> not only <Node5,Node6>.
Please suggest some efficient algorithm for this fetching root node.

```
GroupA
   -- Node1
   -- Node2
   -- Node3
GroupB
   --Node4
   --SubGroupB
        --Node5
        --Node6
GroupC
   --Node7

XML representation
      <GroupA>
          <id>1001</id>
          <Node1><id>1002</id></Node1>
          <Node2><id>1003</id></Node2>
          <Node3><id>1004</id></Node3>
      <GroupB>
          <id>1005</id></id>
          <Node4><id>1006</id></Node4>
          <sub-group>
             <id>1007</id>
             <Node5><id>1008</id></Node5>
             <Node6><id>1009</id></Node6>
          </sub-group>
      <GroupC>
          <id>1007</id>
          <Node7><id>1010</id></Node6>
```

Comment: You entered `id` as element. Therefore `id` would be a node also. I would define `id` as attribute.

Comment: If there is no sort order you can rely on then, you'll have to traverse your tree to find the node and remember which group you are in. If there is a sort order, you would use binary search. Don't see what is the problem here.